# What's the Ruby equivalent of Python's output[:-1]?

Tags: python, ruby

In Python, if I want to get the first n characters of a string minus the last character, I do:

```
output = 'stackoverflow'
print output[:-1]
```

What's the Ruby equivalent?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't want to get too nitpicky, but if you want to be more like Python's approach, rather than doing `"StackOverflow"[0..-2]` you can do `"StackOverflow"[0...-1]` for the same result.

In Ruby, a range with 3 dots excludes the right argument, where a range with two dots includes it.  So, in the case of string slicing, the three dots is a bit more close to Python's syntax.

Comment: Now, that made me read the docs for Range again and learn about triple dots for the first time. Nice!

Comment: My gripe with two-dots vs. three-dots is it's easy to mistake/miscount the number of dots, increasing the chance of a bug or making maintenance a bit more difficult. In my opinion, using three is more of a curiosity as it really doesn't help me write clearer code.

Comment: @Z.E.D.: One of the use cases for 3-dot ranges is running a case statement over floats.   See page 97 of the Pickaxe book for Ruby 1.9, if you have it.

Answer (score 4):

Your current Ruby doesn't do what you describe: it cuts off the last character, but it also reverses the string.

The closest equivalent to the Python snippet would be

```
output = 'stackoverflow'
puts output[0...-1]
```

You originally used `..` instead of `...` (which would work if you did `output[0..-2]`); the former being closed–closed the latter being closed–open. Slices—and most everything else—in Python are closed–open.

Comment: You can choose whether a range includes its end. Two dots (`0..-2`) includes the last element while the three-dot form (`0...-1`) excludes it.

Answer (score 2):

`"stackoverflow"[0..-2]` will return `"stackoverflo"`

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is remove the last character of the string, you can use the 'chop' method as well:

```
puts output.chop
```

or

```
puts output.chop!
```

Comment: Note that `chop` will remove two characters if the string ends in `\r\n`.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to remove the last character, you can also do

```
output.chop
```